# how to create an array of objects in node.js

Tags: node.js

i am trying to get my data in the format below, like an array of objects, like below

```
var schema = [
  {name: 'Name', type: 'STRING'},
  {name: 'Age', type: 'INTEGER'},
  {name: 'Weight', type: 'FLOAT'},
  {name: 'IsMagic', type: 'BOOLEAN'},
];
```

but I can't seem to figure out how, my first attempt was to create an object and then add the objects to an array but I'm having difficulties

Comment: this is a vague question. Sir, please try to be more descriptive about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First creating an empty array and then adding item to it will be most simple way to do this. Code should look like

```
let myArray:any[] = [];

myArray.push({name: 'Name', type: 'STRING'});// adding single object
myArray.push( [...{name: 'Age', type: 'INTEGER'},{name: 'Weight', type: 'FLOAT'},{name: 'IsMagic', type: 'BOOLEAN'}]);//adding multiple objects at a time
```